# plugin for google chrome

Tags: c++, windows, plugins, google-chrome

I am using windows xp and i want to develop my own plugin for google chrome using cpp like other plugins(flash or silverlite) because i have my own exe file so when particular page is open it find for plugins and if plugin is not installed on the system then it first ask to install that plugin form the server and if plugin is already installed then it will not ask and started service.

so anybody knows such type of example or any related tutorial then please tell me.

thank you in advance to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NPAPI is not an easy API to use directly, IMO. However, there are frameworks that make the creation of plug-ins much easier. See:

[FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org) - "*a framework that allows easy creation of powerful browser plugins*"

[nixysa](http://code.google.com/p/nixysa/) - "*A glue code generation framework for NPAPI plugins*"

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [NPAPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI)  or [PPAPI](http://code.google.com/p/ppapi/).

NPAPI works in firefox and chrome.

PPAPI is chrome only and is experimental.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome supports the NAPI interface for plugins. Check out:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Plugins